# Remove Duplicate Records From Left Join

Tags: sql-server-2014, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I work with Microsoft Dynamics Navision 2013 and SQL 2014 as the data source. The Value entry table is the main table that host all sales transaction for customers / Items.

For some of the items we pay Excise (Tax), a certain rate we pay for all items being transferred from one warehouse to another which we call (Transfer Excise).

I work for a wine farm and for each year we enter a unit rate for each item per location(Location being the warehouse where the wine is stored before transfer out of the warehouse]. Our unit rate was created on the 28-02-28.

In order to get the calculation for the Transfer Excise I took data from various tables from Microsoft Dynamics Navision. The tables are containing the columns I took:

```
Location : Code, also contains a filter “NONBOND”

Item: No(PK) , Excise Type

Excise Rate: Starting Date (The starting date of the Unit Rate), Excise Type Code

Item Unit Of Measure: Item No(PK), Qty_ per unit of measure as (Litre Conversion Factor)
```

The data was entered into a new table called `Transfer Excise Tbl 1`. To simplify my example, my `Transfer Excise` table contains: `No_ and Location Code` (FK) my Value Entry Table contains `Item No_`(PK) , `Location Code`(PK). Of course I will join `Transfer Excise` and `Value Entry` table on (`No_=Item No_`) and `Location code = Location code`.

I'm trying to get all item transactions which match the `Value Entry` table for each unit rate for that specific starting date and the posting date when the transaction were posted using `LEFT JOIN` with filters.

In the Value Entry table I use `Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group` to filter only (`LOCA` & `EXSA`), `LOCA` meaning local and `EXSA` meaning Export South Africa. This is the query I am trying, however I get duplicates with no starting dates and posting dates. I tried using `DISTINCT` as seen in my query but it does not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.[Starting Date],  
                 b.[Posting Date], 
              b.[Item No_],  
           b.[Invoiced Quantity],  
           a.[Litre Conversion Factor], 
           a.[Unit Rate] , 
              a.[Location Code],  
           a.[Excise Location], 
           a.[Excise Type Code], 
           a.[Unit Of Measure Code]
FROM [Transfer Excise Tbl] a
LEFT JOIN [Spier Live$Value Entry] b
    ON a.[No_] = b.[Item No_] 

WHERE  b.[Posting Date] > '2014-03-01'
AND b.[Item No_] = 'F00335'
AND b.[Location Code] = a.[Location Code]
AND b.[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group] IN ('LOCA','EXSA')
AND b.[Posting Date] >= a.[Starting Date]
AND b.[Invoiced Quantity] <>0
order by b.[Posting Date]
```

Comment: Firstly, your `WHERE` criteria is turning your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Try moving to be part of the `ON` condition. Secondly, please post the DDL of the relevant tables.

Comment: @Chris , I did a ddl but when I want to add it to the comment box it says it is to long

Comment: @Chris , how do I properbly paste the ddl result for you

Comment: Edit your question